# Laravel mailgun

Tags: laravel, mailgun

i have a small problem. When i am sending a contact information from my page i am receiving all the content of that page as a message. I have checked stackoverflow answers and i did everything like at larvel official web page. I figured out how to put the subject, sender email and name. I can't undersand how to make a view with text message. My code and routes looks like that:

```
Route::resource('contact-us', 'SendEmailController',['names'=>[


    'store'=>'contact-us.store'

]]);


  public function store(Request $request){
       $subject =$request->subject;
 $content  =  $request->body;
    $email = $request->email;
     $name =   $request->name;

    Mail::send('contact-us', ['email' => $email, 'name' => $name], function ($m) use ($email, $name) {
        $m->from($email, $name);

        $m->to('snaix93@gmail.com' , 'Alex')->subject('Your Reminder!');
    });
```

the form from contact view

```
 {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> 'SendEmailController@store']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Subject </label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" >
        </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name </label>
                 <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email *</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('body', 'Message:') !!}
                    {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class'=>'form-control','rows'=>3])!!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::submit('Submit Message', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code so others have an easier time reading and understanding it

Comment: can you post a code of view `contact-us` ?

Comment: in contact-us is all the navigation and the content. Is too long and  i can't post it here.  The form from above is from contact-us. Even  i will put the form in another view the message that i am receiving on my email is the form with input subject , email and content.